# Intercepting specific messages between applications in Android (similar to snapchat)

Tags: android, web-services, sms

I'm implementing an application, with functionality similar to snapchat,
and I was wondering if I would be able to send an sms from one device in Android
to another, containing video/audio/picture/text.

I want the message contents to be intercepted and stored for view inside of the application,
not in the general messaging folder on the device.

What would be my best plan of attack to do this?  I would like the user to be notified when a new message were to appear.

Would I implement a push/pull framework?  I have access to a server, could I store the content and then have the other device poll the database?

If possible, I would much rather have the sms sent and stored.

Comment: Then what would be the best way to check a server database for a new message from another user.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be my best plan of attack to do this?

Don't bother, as it will not work on Android 4.4+. All SMS/MMS messages will be delivered to the user's default SMS/MMS client, and you have no means of stopping it.